# How do I stop a jQuery animation on my website from repeating itself or being re-triggered?

Tags: jquery, animation

Please visit http://davidurbonas.com/website/ and scroll down to the "skills" section. You'll the progress bars start and finish. When they finish scroll down a bit as if you were reading the rest of my site and then scroll up again to the section again. You'll see the percentage starting all over again with the previous go around still there (hopefully you see what I mean by that).

How do I make the animation only play once for my progress bars? I'm using waypoints (script) to trigger the animations  and CProgress for the bars themselves. I've set parameters so that the bars don't all start at the same time.

Here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        setpara();

        $('#timeline').waypoint(function(direction) {
            myplugin = $('#p1').cprogress(options);
            setTimeout(function() {
                myplugin = $('#p2').cprogress(options2);
            }, 500);
            setTimeout(function() {
                myplugin = $('#p3').cprogress(options3);
            }, 1000);
            setTimeout(function() {
                myplugin = $('#p4').cprogress(options4);
            }, 1500);
            setTimeout(function() {
                myplugin = $('#p5').cprogress(options5);
            }, 2000);
            setTimeout(function() {
                myplugin = $('#p6').cprogress(options6);
            }, 2500);
            var myplugin;
        }); 


    });
    function setpara(){
        options = {
            img1: 'img/v1.png',
            img2: 'img/v2.png',           
            speed: 0,        
            percent: 0,
            limit: 85,
            showPercent : true, //show hide percent
            onComplete: function(p){console.log('complete',p);$("#p1 .percent").html(p+"%");}
        };
        options2 = {
            img1: 'img/v1.png',
            img2: 'img/v2.png',           
            speed: 0,        
            percent: 0,
            limit: 100,
            showPercent : true, //show hide percent
            onInit: function(){console.log('init');},
            onProgress: function(p){/*console.log('progress',p);*/},
            onComplete: function(p){console.log('complete',p);$("#p2 .percent").html(p+"%");}
        };
        options3 = {
            img1: 'img/v1.png',
            img2: 'img/v2.png',           
            speed: 0,        
            percent: 0,
            limit: 95,
            showPercent : true, //show hide percent
            onInit: function(){console.log('init');},
            onProgress: function(p){/*console.log('progress',p);*/},
            onComplete: function(p){console.log('complete',p);$("#p3 .percent").html(p+"%");}
        };
        options4 = {
            img1: 'img/v1.png',
            img2: 'img/v2.png',           
            speed: 0,        
            percent: 0,
            limit: 75,
            showPercent : true, //show hide percent
            onInit: function(){console.log('init');},
            onProgress: function(p){/*console.log('progress',p);*/},
            onComplete: function(p){console.log('complete',p);$("#p4 .percent").html(p+"%");}
        };
        options5 = {
            img1: 'img/v1.png',
            img2: 'img/v2.png',           
            speed: 0,        
            percent: 0,
            limit: 45,
            showPercent : true, //show hide percent
            onInit: function(){console.log('init');},
            onProgress: function(p){/*console.log('progress',p);*/},
            onComplete: function(p){console.log('complete',p);$("#p5 .percent").html(p+"%");}
        };
        options6 = {
            img1: 'img/v1.png',
            img2: 'img/v2.png',           
            speed: 0,        
            percent: 0,
            limit: 90,
            showPercent : true, //show hide percent
            onInit: function(){console.log('init');},
            onProgress: function(p){/*console.log('progress',p);*/},
            onComplete: function(p){console.log('complete',p);$("#p6 .percent").html(p+"%");}
        };

    }

</script>
```

I have tried using .stop() but it doesn't work for me. I could just be putting in the wrong spot. My jQuery is not that strong yet :(

Comment: Where did you put the `.stop()`?

Comment: I tried putting everywhere, lol. Where would you put it? I'll try anything anyone suggests.

Comment: Look into jQuery's [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/). You'd probably apply it on the line `$('#timeline').waypoint(function(direction) {` somewhere but I am not sure without testing. Also, your page is super bulky, you should try to minimize the load time by cutting things out and improving the performance